# CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture vs Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture vs regional settings

Tags: c#, windows, cultureinfo

here I have a windows 10 Computer, that seems to be running with german regional settings and the display language also seems to be german.
In my C# programm when I use these two properties, I get some inconsistent results:

`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` returns `de-DE` as expected.
`CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture` instead returns `en-US` and that is not expected.

Nowhere in the control panels or system settings of windows I could find a hint, as that `en-US` seems to be installed.

I need to know what the current display language is, because if the user does not specify any other language (or a faulty one) on the command line of my program, it should fall back to the current language that the system is using.

Should I simply specify the fall back as

`CultureInfo fallback = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;`

Or why is `CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture` different to what I expect it?

Greetings Wolfgang

Comment: It says; "represents the culture installed with the operating system." So this means an English edition of Windows is installed on your server. It seems to be independent of the cultures you have installed later for display and input, and should not affect (afaik) your app. Defaulting to `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;` seems ok.

Comment: @OguzOzgul, I will have to have a look at the program, because it is so complex, and some stupid folk remembered the users language selection and used this as a parameter to every function where it may be needed to display text. But with `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` and `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` it should be easily enough to determine the correct language...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to solve this problem was to rely on

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture
```

This is the correct setting for language dependend texts, while

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
```

represents the formatting of date and time and numbers and currencies